# Tables are coming on different pages and in the end with this APA template

Tags: tables, apa-style, apa7

I am using this [APA7 template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-and-sample-for-authoring-apa7-manuscripts/pvhtwcrvcmsp) for an assignment, and when I add a table, it takes it to the end of the document, beyond the reference list even. It does not matter which placement modifiers like `htbp`, `h!`, `H` or anything I use, the tables go to the end. Furthermore, each of the two tables I have inserted go on a different page, even though both can fit on one.

Comment: that is  by design and a requirement for submitting to apa journals,  the class has a `floatsintext` option if you want normal floats for personal drafts (or do not use the `man` option)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Thank you for clarifying.